# mysql how to select count of rows group by sun_calendar_date and div to periodic by every x day

Tags: mysql, sql

This question as I think needs a function, but every solution is acceptable.
I have a table like below :
sun_calendar_date is integer and its easy for me to convert it to string,

answerset:

```
id       sun_calendar_date      data
-------------------------------------------
1             13980120            something
2             13980122            something
3             13980129            something
4             13980130            something
5             13980131            something(end of month)
6             13980201            something
7             13980202            something
8             13980103            something
9             13980103            something
```

I want to select count of rows group by sun_calendar_date and div to periodic by every x day
for example

for example for period 5 days I had the code below but not working for next month and empty days:

```
SELECT  COUNT(answerset.id) as val,sun_calendar_date FROM answerset
WHERE id  group by SUBSTRING(sun_calendar_date,7,2) div 5;
```

I need this:

```
val        sun_calendar_date
-------------------------------------
2             13980120            20-24=> 2 rows
1             13980129            25-29=> 1 rows
5             13980130            30-03=> 5 rows (next month)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below to solve your problem:

```
DELIMITER ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS answerset;

CREATE TABLE answerset
(
id INTEGER,
sun_calendar_date DATE,
data VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO answerset VALUES (1,'13980120','something'),
(2,'13980122','something'),
(3,'13980129','something'),
(4,'13980130','something'),
(5,'13980131','something(end of month)'),
(6,'13980201','something'),
(7,'13980202','something'),
(8,'13980203','something'),
(9,'13980203','something');

-- We need a variable as we need a place to start. You could also set this to whatever date you want
-- if you need to avoid using a variable.
DECLARE @minDate DATE;

SELECT MIN(sun_calendar_date) INTO @minDate FROM answerset;

-- Here we use modulo ((%) returns the remainder of a division) and FLOOR which removes decimal places (you could also
-- convert to INT too). This gives us the number of days after the minimum date grouped into 5s. You could
-- also replace 5 with a variable if you need to change the size of your groups.

SELECT DATE_ADD(sun_calendar_date, INTERVAL -FLOOR((DATEDIFF(sun_calendar_date, @minDate))) % 5 DAY) AS PeriodStart,
MIN(sun_calendar_date) AS Period,
COUNT(DISTINCT sun_calendar_date) AS Val
FROM answerset
GROUP BY DATE_ADD(sun_calendar_date, INTERVAL -FLOOR((DATEDIFF(sun_calendar_date, @minDate))) % 5 DAY)
ORDER BY sun_calendar_date;
```

Comment: No sir, sometime in one day we have tow records, there is not mistake or error in data set

Comment: Ok, I've added back in the data and added in an extra column. One for the start date of the group and one for the MIN, so where there's only one record it will show this date in the Period field, e.g. 13980129.

Answer (score 0):

You need an auxiliary calendar table. I tried to get this table from the [`information_schema.columns`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html) table.

```
select
  min(a.sun_calendar_date) qnt,
  count(a.sun_calendar_date) sun_calendar_date
from (
  select
    @seq beg,
    @seq := adddate(@seq, 5) fin
  from (
    select
      max(sun_calendar_date) x,
      @seq := adddate(min(sun_calendar_date),
                      -(day(min(sun_calendar_date)) % 5))
    from answerset
  ) init
  cross join information_schema.columns c1
  cross join information_schema.columns c2
  where @seq <= init.x
) calendar
join answerset a
  on a.sun_calendar_date >= calendar.beg and
     a.sun_calendar_date < calendar.fin
group by calendar.beg;
```

**Output:**

```
|    qnt     | sun_calendar_date |
+------------+-------------------+
| 1398-01-20 |                 2 |
| 1398-01-29 |                 1 |
| 1398-01-30 |                 5 |
```

Test it online with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7ec3c/20).

MySQL 8.0 with [recursive CTEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive):

```
with recursive
  init as (
    select
      adddate(min(sun_calendar_date),
              -(day(min(sun_calendar_date)) % 5)) beg,
      max(sun_calendar_date) x
    from answerset
  ),
  calendar(beg, fin, x) as (
    select beg, adddate(beg, 5), x from init
    union all
    select fin, adddate(fin, 5), x from calendar where fin <= x
  )
select
  min(a.sun_calendar_date) qnt,
  count(a.sun_calendar_date) sun_calendar_date
from answerset a
join calendar c
  on a.sun_calendar_date >= c.beg and a.sun_calendar_date < c.fin
group by c.beg;
```

Test it online with [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ffbded0a31fe3b81683ae46e083fcc8).